# Lightning email can't enter message

Tags: lightning, email, email-template

when I click on email tab I only see related and no way to enter message. Also the icons for templates are missing, See the following:
[image]

Comment: Just a few questions. Does this happen to more users or just you? Are all computers affected or just yours? If just one, what browser are you using? Have you tried a hard refresh (control F5 on windows) of the page? What happens in a different browser?

Comment: Currently I am the only one using Salesforce, and I am setting it up. It was working last week. however i move over a change set from my sandbox and it stopped working.

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome, and Edge and I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: i have done a number of Hard Refresh in both Chrome and Edge. Also checked my settings in Chrome to ensure that JavaScript was enabled.

Comment: Are you working in a sandbox? The standard setting for sandboxes is not to have access to email deliverability. Check this link under email deliverability and see if that helps: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&type=5

Comment: no I am having this issue in Production. I have opened a Case with Salesforce support on this and I am currently working with them I will up this issue when I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So If you see missing Icons or fields you need to do the following:
Setup -> Global actions -> Send email -> Layout -> (Dragging and dropping all the available options present there).
[image]

Comment: I think this happen when I did a change set from a sandbox to Production. I update a Opportunity Screen and all of the related. However this is just a guess.